# How to merge or handle fan page and app page?

Tags: facebook

First, I'm new to the whole Facebook page and apps.  I have had a page created long ago for all my app fans here:
http://www.facebook.com/xiialive

However, now my Android app allows user to post what they are listening to Facebook. The problem is that I can't set my Facebook app to point to my old fan page so I had to create a new one:  http://www.facebook.com/pages/XiiaLive-Internet-Radio/134321196699146

I just don't want to be supporting two pages... Seems a bit weird... How can I handle this situation? Any ideas? Possibly redirect automatically to my old fan page?

Any tips how to handle this situation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Comment why if you are requesting a close.... THANKS!!

Comment: This has been asked before,many times and is usually closed as off topic - here's an answer i gave before - http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9791279/using-existing-page-as-app-page - short answer: this is not possible, you need to create a new page for the app, and can merge an existing page onto it if that option is available to you (which may or may not be the case, i'm not sure how page merges work)

Comment: Well, I did find many questions about how to set fan page to app page and similar answers I found... "You can't" However, since I'm new to this and I wanted a possible direction to what it's recommended. This has to be one of the most common situations.  You merge suggestion would be great... But I'm not sure if that is even possible?

Comment: If you have a sales rep at facebook they can definitely help with page merges, i'm not sure how the self-serve option works or if it's available to everyone